# wsdl2java does not generate all stubs java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl2java, cybersource

I was trying to generate java codes via wsdl2java, and have been trying out all the possible arguments but still unable to get the java (ITransactionProcessor) for below :

https://ics2wstesta.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Some more details on what you tried and what were the results would be helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

There is some rather old but probably still useful documentation that goes into great detail on the steps to build a CyberSource Java SOAP client using wsdl2java.

See Chapter 9 of this [document](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/SOAP_Toolkits/SOAP_toolkits.pdf).

Here is wsdl2java command from that document:
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java -p **com.cybersource.stub**
https://ics2wstesta.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.151.wsdl

Where **com.cybersource.stub** is the package name that will be used for the generated
classes.

If you can provide some more details about how you are building the java code and what the results look like I will probably be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: I have been playing with different arguments but still unable to get the certain java.

wsdl2java.sh -p com.cybersource.stub -d xmlbeans -s -ss –g -uri https://ics2wstesta.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.151.wsdl

wsdl2java.sh -p com.cybersource.stub -a -u -uri https://ics2wstesta.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.151.wsdl